# could not get a json data from a link

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

this is my script , i am unable to get the json data from the link , please hep me , point out if i am wrong anywhere , thank u in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function getsomethin()
          //wait for HTML document
          {
              alert("l");
              $.getJSON('http://developers-blog.org/resources/jquery-ajax/heroes-list.json', function (data) {
                  console.log(data);                  alert(data);
                  $.each(data, function (i, name) {
                      $("div").append(name + " ");
                  });
              });
          }       

    </script>
```

Comment: You can't retrieve json with an ajax call to a different domain. You can look into using jsonp.

Comment: Are you trying to do a cross-domain Ajax request? If developers-blog.org supports it you'll need to do a jsonp request. Otherwise you'll need to do an Ajax request to your own webserver and have your webserver request the data from developers-blog.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use [JsonP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for cross domain Request.

"jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.

try like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://developers-blog.org/resources/jquery-ajax/heroes-list.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?",  function(data) {
        console.log(data);                  alert(data);
                  $.each(data, function (i, name) {
                      $("div").append(name + " ");
    });
});
```

Comment: Note that this changes the _client-side_ code to make a jsonp request, but it won't actually work unless that particular url points to a server-side process that supports jsonp too. (Which it doesn't.)

Comment: hi @nnnnnn i edited the snippet as 
var url =  "http://developers-blog.org/resources/jquery-ajax/heroes-list.json";
    $.getJSON(url + "?callback=?" 
but it still not working the alert(data) itself not working

Comment: @user1386579 - Yes, it's not ever going to work for that url because that url returns a plain JSON file. It doesn't support jsonp requests. (You can instead do a standard Ajax call to your own web-server and have your web-server get that JSON from developers-blog.org and in turn pass it back to your JS.)

Answer (score 0):

you need jsonp if its crossdomain

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/.../file.json',
    data: 'param=3',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results) {
        //callback
    },
    complete: function() {
        //callback
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: jsonp only works if handled appropriately on client _and_ server.

Answer (score 0):

i went ahead with this format to get the data from the link , it worked , thank u guys for ur support

```
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
        {
            alert(xmlHttp.status);
            if(xmlHttp.status==200)
            {

            alert("hi");
            var jsondata=eval("("+xmlHttp.responseText+")") //retrieve result as an JavaScript object
            jsonOutput=jsondata.message.result;
            alert(jsonOutput);

            InitializeLeadStorage()

        }
        }
```